# A problem related to linear assignment with constraints.

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Suppose I have two sets of numbers $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$, an integer $m < n$, and a number $r\ge0$. I wish to choose a subset $C$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with $|C|=m$ that solves the following problem:

$$
\text{maximise }\sum_{i\in C}a_i \\
\text{s.t. } \sum_{i\in C}b_i \ge r
$$

I don't have much experience in optimisation. My question is: does an efficient way to solve this problem exist, and can you refer to me an algorithm that might help? In the context of where I would apply such an algorithm, a typical value of $n$ would be around $100$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems NP-hard. For example, I can reduce the decision problem of knapsack to this problem as follows. The decision problem for knapsack asks whether a total value of at least $V$ can be achieved with total weight not exceeding $W$. Here, we set $a_i$ equal to negative the weight of the $i$-th object, and we set $b_i$ equal to its value. We then set $r$ to be equal to $V$. Now, there exists a solution for the knapsack problem whose total value is at least $V$ if and only if the maximum value of $\sum a_i$ is at least $-W$.

However, there's the constraint $m$ in your problem. I recall that the equivalent knapsack problem in which we have to take exactly $m$ items is at least NP-hard as well, but I don't have reference to it.

Note that since $n$ is around $20$, trying all possible sets of $m$ objects out of $n$ objects in most modern computers should run very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's a shame. I had actually mistakenly given that value of $n=20$; in actuality it will be closer to $n=100$. You're right in that simply trying all possibilities for $n<$ around $20$ runs fairly quickly, but there is an unacceptable slowdown for $n$ much larger. Perhaps a probabilistic approach would work, trying only a random subset of the assignments. How accurate do you think this would be?

Comment: @scrambledeggs I don't know, but my guess is it won't be pretty good in the worst possible input. I would go with the approximation algorithms with known bounds such as the 2-approx linear integer program approximations. Edit: I don't know if it's possible to incorporate $m$ into the linear program though.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll take a look at that.